# Error when trying to use stored procedure in crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2016

The error:

```
 Database Connector Error: '22018:[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Conversion 
 failed when converting the nvarchar value '%' to data type int. [Database Vendor Code: 245]'
```

The stored procedure contains one parameter that is data type int.  There is not a % anywhere in the procedure nor are there any calculations using the int data type.

Answer (score 0):

Does the SP attempt to cast an nvarchar column to an integer?
If so, make sure all the values in that column are indeed numbers.

It may be easier to spot the issue if you post the SP code.